# Accessing local files inside the debug folder of a UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to open a file inside the local folder where the UWP's app files are deployed during debug.
The location is something like
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\{appId}VS.Debug_x86.{username}

This happens when I try to execute the following code:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream) new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)))
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();`
```

The exception is

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path {path} is
>   denied.'

Comment: you need to use a special URL format to access those files: ms-appx:///path/to/the/file.ext

Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: That didn't work. I ended up using `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)`